# PostGIS points to multipoint error

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a table on PostgreSQL 9.2 ("POSTGIS="2.0.1 r9979" GEOS="3.3.3-CAPI-1.7.4" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" LIBXML="2.8.0""). This is it:

```
CREATE TABLE nearest_point (
  id_nearest_point serial NOT NULL,
  id_iri_radartec integer,
  id_tramo integer,
  geom geometry(GeometryZ,4326),
  CONSTRAINT pk_nearest_point PRIMARY KEY (id_nearest_point)
);
```

[image: SELECT nearest_point]

I need a geometry that represents the point set union of the Geometries. Easy.

```
SELECT id_tramo
   ,ST_Multi(ST_Union(np.geom)) AS geom
  FROM nearest_point AS np
GROUP BY id_tramo;
```

But I get this:

[image: Zoom out - 01]

"ST_Union GROUP BY" points in pink.

And the other points?

[image: Zoom out - 02]

The arrow indicates where are the points of the table nearest_point.
Where is my error?

Comment: Have you tried `ST_Collect` instead of ST_Union?